# How to install CouchDB 2 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian-stretch, software-compilation, database

I've tried installing CouchDB 2.1.0 and 2.1.1 on Raspbian Stretch following the instructions in this blog: http://andyfelong.com/2017/09/couchdb-2-1-on-raspberry-pi-raspbian-stretch/

However when I run the step `make release` I get a segmentation fault when trying 2.1.1 and the following error when trying 2.1.0:

```
/home/couchdb/apache-couchdb-2.1.0/src/couch/src/couch_httpd_db.erl:none: internal error in v3_kernel;
crash reason: {case_clause,[]}

  in function  v3_kernel:arg_con/1 (v3_kernel.erl, line 1531)
  in call from v3_kernel:is_var_clause/1 (v3_kernel.erl, line 1512)
  in call from v3_kernel:partition/1 (v3_kernel.erl, line 1076)
  in call from v3_kernel:match/4 (v3_kernel.erl, line 1006)
  in call from v3_kernel:match_clause/4 (v3_kernel.erl, line 1408)
  in call from lists:mapfoldl/3 (lists.erl, line 1354)
  in call from lists:mapfoldl/3 (lists.erl, line 1355)
  in call from v3_kernel:'-match_con_1/4-anonymous-0-'/3 (v3_kernel.erl, line 1136)
Compiling /home/couchdb/apache-couchdb-2.1.0/src/couch/src/couch_httpd_db.erl failed:
ERROR: compile failed while processing /home/couchdb/apache-couchdb-2.1.0/src/couch: rebar_abort
Makefile:67: recipe for target 'couch' failed
make: *** [couch] Error 1
```

Previously I installed CouchDB 1.2 on Wheezy, from apt-get, which was easy and worked well.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Erlang package that comes with Debian Stretch, not the one from the Erlang Solutions repository:

```
sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends -y install \
    build-essential pkg-config erlang \
    libicu-dev libmozjs185-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Then install Couch from source as per the instructions on the official site:

http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/install/unix.html#debian-based-systems

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error message, it appears that Erlang is crashing with an internal error ("internal error in v3_kernel"). My initial thoughts regarding the issue seem to have been incorrect, and the ARM build isn't being hung up for the reason I initially thought.

In fact, the error message is proving rather elusive. I'd guess that Erlang is either installed incorrectly, or broken somehow.  As suggested in a question about a [similar internal error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37856692/feodra-22-want-to-build-couchdb), it may be helpful to purge Erlang from your system, then reinstall it. To do this, try:

```
apt-get remove erlang
apt-get purge erlang
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/erlang
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/erlang
apt-get install erlang
```

This should ensure that your installation is working correctly. I'd then try installing a fresh copy of CouchDB (perhaps try 2.1.1 too?).

Comment: Thanks, but after this change it still doesn't work. Firstly the `./bootstrap` command fails with "ebin/rebar.bea#: error writing file: no such file or directory", and `make clean; make release` fails with "Illegal instruction".

Comment: @EricClack Hmm, looking at the error message, it looks like Erlang might be the issue here. Could you check your Erlang version (the [command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9561398/6650102) is `erl -eval 'erlang:display(erlang:system_info(otp_release)), halt().'  -noshell` in your terminal)?

Comment: "19", and here's the output from `dpkg-query --list` "ii  erlang                   1:19.2.1+dfsg-2+d all               Concurrent, real-time, distributed functional language"

Comment: @EricClack Thanks; I've revised my answer with what I could gather from your error message, and as far as I can tell, the issue is with Erlang and not CouchDB. Take a read and let me know if any of the steps help.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It still fails, here's the error: "Compiled src/global_changes_sup.erl
Segmentation fault
Makefile:67: recipe for target 'couch' failed
make: *** [couch] Error 139"

Comment: Is there an Erlang test suite I can try, just to see if I can isolate the problem and rule out CouchDB?

Comment: Also I've posted this: https://github.com/apache/couchdb/issues/1103

Comment: @EricClack Sounds like you hit a new, different Erlang issue causing it to segfault. I'm not aware of an Erlang test suite, but I'm not too familiar with Erlang either, so it might be a good idea to see what the CouchDB folks say/contact an Erlang mailing list as appropriate. Could you double check which version of Erlang is installed now, after purging everything? My only guess is that perhaps the version that got reinstalled is out of date.

Comment: I think it was caused by Erlang. I discovered that there is an Erlang package in Debian Stretch, so used this instead and all seems to work fine. Thanks for your help.